# Which answer of these two answers is the correct one? and why?

Tags: pronouns

.... a good thing you didn’t get caught.

a) That's

b) It's

the answer given by the teacher is (a) but I think that both seem correct

Comment: As a native BrE speaker I would nearly always say (b)

Comment: As a native US English speaker, I would also nearly always say (b).  In (b), *it* is kind of a "dummy it", just referring to the fact that you didn't get caught, but *that* doesn't really have the same dummy usage.

Comment: Definitely (b).  "That" is specific and needs to refer to an actual thing.  "It" is non-specific, e.g. "It's a sunny day somewhere" doesn't identify where the sunny day is, it's just a placeholder for some notional sunny day.  Likewise, "it's a good thing you didn't get caught" isn't an actual 'good thing', it's just a placeholder for the idea of a good thing.

Comment: What @ColinM. ***It's / That's*** why we don't say *That's raiining*, or *That's time for bed*.